# Export multiple reports to Excel

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, reporting

I have a c# windows form that opens up a report viewer (using visual studio reports). The first report shown is an overview report displaying various figures split by year. Each year can then be clicked on and a drill through report is opened up passing the date as a parameter where a more detailed view is shown.

Is there a way of exporting this overview report and its drill through reports to one excel workbook with the reports separated as worksheets? I can save each report separately but I need the option of saving them all to one workbook automatically. So the excel file looks essentially the same as it does on the report viewer. I've searched everywhere and not found a clear solution.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it, u probably will need to write you own xls writer to make it work.